# Getting "null is disabled" warning for log messages with scala wart remover

Tags: scala, scala-wartremover

Wart remover complains about log messages. Why does it complain? How to get rid of wart remover warnings for log messages?

```
[wartremover:Null] null is disabled
[warn]           logger.error(e)
[warn]                       ^
```

Comment: How is `e` declared?

Comment: `e` is an Exception. Even if i replace `e` with string like this `logger.error("Some error")`, then also I get the same warning.

Comment: What is the return type of `logger.error`?

Comment: Return type is `Unit`